# An abstract policy function?

Tags: cakephp

Much of the authorization and policy of the website I'm creating is wrapped up in group policy, not single user policy. There are some functions, such as searching for the existence of a user group in a user's profile, which need to be repeated over and over again. Since policies don't extend anything, would it be possible for a developer to create some sort of abstract policy object which included this function?

Comment: When you say "_abstract policy object_", what exactly do you mean? A policy class that extends [**an `abstract` class**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)?

Comment: I mean that, whereas Entities extend the Entity class, there is no base object for Policies. But I could create a Policy class that my policies could extend, and in this class I could hold those functions that get used frequently in child objects?

Comment: I suggest you take this question to the [CakePHP Forum](https://discourse.cakephp.org/) and find out more on how to decorate library/core logic.

Answer (score 0):

Policy classes do not need to extend base classes, you are free to extend whatever custom class you want. What matters is that the policy class provides the required policy check methods (which vary depending on the resource).

The only slight exception are policies for requests, they *should* (but currently do not have to) implement `\Authorization\Policy\RequestPolicyInterface`, however this doesn't stop you from extending classes or implementing additional interfaces.